# How can I start the python shell and automatically initialize it with some commands?

Tags: python

I find that when I start the python shell I have a bunch of commands I always type to get into the state I want.  It is tiresome to keep re-typing these commands, so I have bundled them into a script.  Now I just type:

```
execfile('script.py')
```

as soon as I enter the shell, and it goes through all the steps to get me to the state I need to be in.

Now I'd like to take it one step further.  How can I get the python shell to automatically run `script.py` every time I start the shell, so I don't have to keep re-typing even that one line?

Comment: Might be using a sledghammer here, but make a symlink to your `python` executable that runs that command first then the needed file from the cli arg after `python`?  You could name it something different, also.

Comment: If you've run into this problem you would likely be interested in ipython http://ipython.org/.

Comment: are you using the shell to practice or something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [PYTHONSTARTUP](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environment variable

Answer (score 14):

Here's a way without having to mess with environment variables:

For example, if I had a script with the following in it called `script.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("example")
```

I could tell `python` to run this before bringing me to the interpreter with the `-i` flag.

```
$ python -i script.py
example
>>>
```

Comment: I see what you're going for here, but your formatting is pretty strange.  You might want to work on that to make it a bit more clear what you're actually doing... In other words, highlight that the important part is `python -i script.py`.

Comment: @mgilson Does this look better?

Comment: that's about a million times better.  I like it now :).  +1

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use [IPython](http://ipython.org/), if possible. It gives tones of great features, and autoexec is only one of them. But of course, correct answer is mentioned by @mgilston

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called `usercustomize.py`, and place it in your `USER_SITE` directory (which you can find as `import site; site._script()`. This file will be executed every time you start an interpreter.

There's a similar file called `sitecustomize.py` which is executed anytime *anyone* starts Python.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows solution, but I'm sure a Unix equivalent could be done.  I created a file `\MyPythonCode\autoexec.py` (the last line of which is a `print("Autoexec Complete")`) and a BAT file `MyPython.Bat` which has:

```
cd \myPythonCode
python -i autoexec.py
```

I just use the command: `mypython`

to start the Python environment every time, now.